# Como executar métodos de todas as classes que estendem uma interface no symfony

Tags: php, symfony-2, interface, classes-abstratas

Eu precisava de algo semelhante ao que console `doctrine:fixtures:load` em relação a classe `DataFixtureLoader` e a interface `OrderedFixtureInterface` ou seja, eu quero fazer um `Command` onde ele procure todas as classes que estenderam a classe abstrata ou a interface e execute o método da interface.

O problema é que não sei onde consultar essas classes no Symfony.

Como eu faço para listar todas as classes que estendem determinada classe ou interface no Symfony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou dar uma resposta baseada no que o `doctrine/data-fixtures-bundle` faz, e você pode basear seu sistema nisso.

No arquivo `LoadDataFixturesCommand.php`, que é exatamente onde reside o comando `doctrine:fixtures:load`, tem esse bloco de código:

```
$dirOrFile = $input->getOption('fixtures');
if ($dirOrFile) {
    $paths = is_array($dirOrFile) ? $dirOrFile : array($dirOrFile);
} else {
    $paths = array();
    foreach ($this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getBundles() as $bundle) {
        $paths[] = $bundle->getPath().'/DataFixtures/ORM';
    }
}
$loader = new DataFixturesLoader($this->getContainer());
foreach ($paths as $path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $loader->loadFromDirectory($path);
    }
}
```

Primeiro o código verifica se você especificou alguma fixture em especial – senão, ele varre os diretórios `/DataFixtures/ORM` de todos os *bundles* do seu projeto a fim de buscar todas as *fixtures* que estão neles. Em seguida, o comando itera por todos os diretórios para ver se eles são válidos e, enfim, carregar as *fixtures* contidas em cada um deles.

O que você pode fazer é algo parecido: definir um padrão de diretório onde devem residir os arquivos que serão executados, carregá-los, verificar se cada um deles implementa a interface desejada (com a função `class_implements`) e executá-las por meio do método implementado. :)